# Any good resources to train helpdesk workers on the basics of avoiding social engineering attacks?

Tags: untagged

Anyone know any good introductions to the concept of [social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) that I can give to helpdesk workers to help them spot suspicious activity? I'm looking for a few examples and a few tips on how to avoid being caught out.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some listed examples: http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/social-engineering-fundamentals-part-i-hacker-tactics
... but I think your primary defense is basic education and common sense. Test for a rudimentary ability to detect soceng during the hiring process.

Answer (score 2):

Kevin Mitnick - "The Art Of Deception".  Fantastic read.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, tell them not to give out information to people they don't know and can't verify the identity of.

Comment: I was kind of hoping for links to articles and stuff, not just random small tips.

Comment: @rjmunro - Honestly, it all comes down to exactly what joeqwerty said. One could get all verbose and talk about the inticracies of social engineering attacks, but when you boil it down, you end up with the ability to employ common sense.

Comment: @ErikA: One example story from the Kevin Mitnick book (mentioned in another answer) is a hundred times better than any amount of just telling people not to give out information.